# Why is windows launching instead of grub. Bad bios settings? Wrong boot loader location?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, bios

I am attempting to dual boot Linux Mint 17.2 (Cinnamon, 64 bit) and Windows 8.1 on my Acer E 15 (model # E5-573-55W1).

I have successfully installed Mint, but I can't get grub to start in a reasonable way.  Here is what I have done:

1. From Windows, create a new partition on my machine to install Mint onto
2. Created a bootable USB drive
3. Restarted my computer and pressed F2 to enter the bios settings:

   1. Bootmode: UEFI
   2. Secure Boot: Disabled
   3. Boot Order: USB HDD First
4. Mint boots from the USB drive and I install:

   1. The installer didn't recognize that I had windows installed, so I selected the something else option (IE not the remove everything option).
   2. I created 3 new partition from the new partition that I made in windows, one for `/`, one for swap and one for `/home`.

[image]

Now I am confused, as to what my bios settings should be.  I have the following set:

- Bootmode: UEFI
- Secure Boot: Disabled
- Boot order: (see image)

[image]

When I boot, I don't get grub.  I go directly to windows.

---

I know that my install worked because I was able to launch it through the grub on the USB.  I can provide more detailed instructions on this if that would be helpful.

---

Full computer information:

[image]

---

The things that I am suspicious of right now are:

- Bad bios settings
- Wrong boot loader location

---

*Edit*

### Reinstall with different boot loader location

I re-installed and set the `Device for boot loader installation` to sda2 but that didn't make any difference.  Same behavior.

---

*Edit*

### Steps to Boot into Linux Mint (in a unacceptably poor way):

- In bios set the boot order to use the USB HDD
- Grub will be launched.  Press ESC:

[image]

- Now you should be in Grub command mode.  Exit it by typing exit:

[image]

- Now you should be on the Boot Manager page.  From here you can launch *the right* grub (IE the first option):

[image]

- This is what the right grub looks like.  The first option will launch the installed version of linux mint (complete with the username I created during install).  The third option will start windows.

[image]

The only question remaining, is why can't I open this grub on startup?  What bios settings do I need?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer was posted over at askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519610/allowing-boot-of-ubuntu-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-531-with-uefi) and it worked for me.  Thanks @gio900. I have copy & pasted the answer below (to avoid broken links):

> ### So I resolved in the simplest way:
>
> - let boot mode UEFI enable, secure boot enable
> - in bios added the USB boot file of the distribution I want to install as trusted for executing:
>
>   - My bios is: Phoenix SecureCore Tiano Setup
>   - under Boot I flag Boot Mode UEFI
>   - Secure Boot ENABLE
>   - under SECURITY i select: "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"
>   - in "Available File System" i select fs0:$nameofmyusbkey
>   - select [EFI]
>   - select [BOOT]
>   - select BOOTx64.EFI
>   - give it the name "whateveryouwant" then, using tab, select YES.
>   - so I go to the Boot option, then put "whateveryouwant" as first in the Boot priority order
>   - then I was able to start Ubuntu installation in UEFI mode! :)
>
> WARNIG!
>
> before I did all them, I free the space for my partitions under win8,
>   I read so many guide about UEFI and UEFI install (I give advice to do
>   it!), and try in several way. That was the only way I was able to do
>   what I want

Note: In order to add items to the `boot priority order` you must be have `Secure Boot` set to `Enabled`....

Comment: Your screen shots show you as having InsydeH20 firmware.   It had exactly the same boot options?